# @State property in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, swiftui

I defined a delegate class (I need to read and write values inside).

This is what I made:

```
class myClass: NSObject {
private let myBool: (Bool) -> Void

init(onBoolValue: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.myBool = onBoolValue
   }
}
```

below I have an extension with some func etc ...

I'm note very familiar with SwiftUI but I saw that in the viewController is defined this:

```
  @State var delegate: myClass! = nil
```

Since I'm not working with SwiftUI, and I need this @state property to work in UiKit, what is the equal of this definition in UIKit?

I've tried stuff like:

```
    weak var delegate: myClass?
```

But it's not working when I call methods on it (can't read or write or even successfully call my function inside delegate)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct; `@State` is for SwiftUI only, and you are not using SwiftUI. You don't need it in this situation anyway, so just delete that attribute and you're good to go.

If a call like `self.delegate?.doSomething()` appears to do nothing, that is usually because either you failed to assign anything *to* the `delegate` property, or because you assigned the wrong thing to the `delegate` property. Delegation is a well-established pattern (usually accompanied by a protocol), and has been well explained on Stack Overflow already.

However, note that if your delegate is a one-off — that is, it is just a helper class — then it is not a delegate! It's a helper and that's all. You would just say `let helper = MyClass(...)` and you'd be good to go. Delegation is for when you have a *prexisting* instance elsewhere in the app, such as another view controller, and you want to turn to it for advice or send it occasional messages.

Comment: Did you see my statement of the code you would use? Did you read what I said? Did you notice that when this is a helper, not a delegate, I don’t say `weak`?